# Access to events triggered by Napili Template out-of-the-box components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, lightning-community, google-analytics

Is it possible to Access Events triggered by Napili Template standard components (Lightning Community)?

I need to call forceCommunity_analyticsInteraction on onclick event for standard components on Napili Template.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The available Events for communities are listed in the [Lightning Communities Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_basics_supported.htm):

> Events
>
> - forceCommunity:analyticsInteraction
> - force:createRecord
> - force:editRecord
> - force:navigateToSObject
> - force:navigateToList
> - force:navigateToRelatedList
> - force:navigateToURL
> - force:navigateToObjectHome
> - lightning:openFiles
> - force:refreshView
> - forceCommunity:routeChange
> - forceCommunity:setActiveLanguage
> - force:showToast

additionally, you can refer to Lightning [Component Developer Guide: Event Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm)

Furthermore -

> forceCommunity:analyticsInteraction
>
> Tracks events triggered by custom
>   components in Communities and sends the data to Google Analytics.

NOT for Standard component interaction.

If you want to achieve what I think you are trying to do, you are better off using a static resource to track your scoped clicks on standard components.

Comment: Many thanks for this info. I am a beginner developer in Salesforce and it helps a lot. BTW, just listened to SF live Webinar "Lightning Updates: Summer, Winter & Beyond" and they said Not to use "static resources" going forward, but to use SLDS instead. Sr-s will not be available starting winter 2018.

Comment: static resources can always be referenced in lightning components,  with CSP and locker service, as long as your js files are strict mode compliant, this should not be an issue. SLDS is just a CSS framewok.

Comment: Also, it looks like there is no events to catch for clicking on the tab of "Featured Topics & Feeds" component on Napili template (for example), correct?

Comment: How to call functions in static resource if there is no access to .cmp file of the standard components provided by SF? Or there is? I am a beginner Sf developer, what I m missing? Thank you